# query if the data is found - Parse & Swift 3

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to develop an app that provide User sign up and within the UI I want to query if the email is exists or not.

The problem is since I change from swift 2 to swift 3 I got these errors

```
var query = PFObject(className:"User")
        query.whereKey("email", equalTo: email)
        query.findObjectsInBackground {
            (objects, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects {
                    for object in objects {
                        print(object.objectId)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
            }
        }
```

> /Users/**************/SignUpSenderViewController.swift:49:9:
>   Value of type 'PFObject' has no member 'whereKey'
>
> /Users/i*************/SignUpSenderViewController.swift:50:9:
>   Value of type 'PFObject' has no member 'findObjectsInBackground'

any suggestion to solve this challenge ?

Comment: I copied the same code from Parse Documentation, so I can checked if the methods are clear. The problem parse didn't update their API since swift 3 released

Answer (score -1):

I dont know what documentation you checked but the query has to be done this way...

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"_User")
```

Comment: The "_User" is not correct.  "User" is the correct form

Comment: in my case it works only with `Parse.User` or `"_User"`